# Least Square of Multiple Lines

Tags: linear-algebra

If a line can be described as $$ y = mx + c $$ and we have multiple lines, we can have these lines described in matrix form
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -m_1\\1 & -m_2\\ \vdots & \vdots\\1 & -m_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y \\ x\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} c_1\\ c_2\\ \vdots\\ c_n\end{bmatrix} $$
I can get the value of $x$ and $y$ by using least square method. But when we have noise in calculation such as
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -m_1+\delta_1\\1 & -m_2+\delta_2\\ \vdots & \vdots\\1 & -m_n+\delta_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{y} \\ \hat{x}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} c_1+\epsilon_1\\ c_2+\epsilon_2\\ \vdots\\ c_n+\epsilon_n\end{bmatrix} $$
can we calculate the deviation of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ from $x$ and $y$ (or is there any other way to describe that problem)?
Thanks

Comment: Note that the multiple rows in your matrix correspond to multiple data points not to multiple "lines" representing multiple values of the unknown parameter! We seek a single line (value of unknown parameter vector) that best approximates the data using the least-squares criterion.

Comment: You should clearly state your question. It's not obvious that what you want is to find and estimate for the intersection point of the lines! In any case, according to your setup, $m_i$ and $c_i$  have to be known (even if the values come from noisy measurements). For me, the second formulation (with noise) does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you wrote, but here is the usual setup.

Assume a set of $m$ data points $\{(x^{(1)}, y^{(1)}), \dots, (x^{(m)}, y^{(m)})\}$, where $x^{(i)}$ can be viewed as inputs to some function and $y^{(i)}$ as the corresponding outputs. The model assumed is the following
$$
y = f(x; \theta)+n
$$
where $f(x;\theta)$ is a function of the input data and some parameter vector $\theta$, and $n$ is noise (error).

For simplicity, assume $m=3$ and $f(x;\theta) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x$. Hence, we can write
$$
y^{(1)} = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x^{(1)} + n^{(1)} \\
y^{(2)} = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x^{(2)} + n^{(2)} \\
y^{(2)} = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x^{(3)} + n^{(3)} \\
$$
or equivalently, in matrix-vector form
$$
y_d = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x^{(1)}\\
1 & x^{(2)}\\
1 & x^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\theta_0 \\
\theta_1
\end{bmatrix}
+ n_d
= 
X_d \theta + n_d
$$
where subscript $d$ is put to emphasize that the elements correspond to "data" (in contrast to model).

Now, in least-squares the goal is to find $\theta$ minimizing $||n_d||^2 = ||y_d - X_d \theta||^2$. That is, to solve
$$
\min_\theta ||y_d - X_d \theta||^2,
$$
hence, the name least-squares, i.e., you seek the minimum (least) of the (sum of) squares since $||n_d||^2 = (n^{(1)})^2 + (n^{(2)})^2 + (n^{(3)})^2$.

One can show that the solution to this problem is given by
$$\theta = X_d^{+} y_d$$
where $X_d^{+}$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $X_d$.

Comment: In my case, it is not linear regression of a line. I want to find the intersection of lines.